# Graph disconnected in keras Conditional Variational autoencoder

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

I am trying to use a conditional Variational autoencoder in Keras. My X has about 1016 samples and 20 columns and they are all binary sequences and my y has 2 columns with float values. I am getting an error that the graph disconnected.

```
n_z = 5
inputs = concat([X, cond],axis=-1)
in_layer=tf.keras.layers.Reshape((inputs.shape[1],1))(inputs)
h_q =  Bidirectional(LSTM(16,activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))(in_layer)
h_q=tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(h_q)
h_q= Bidirectional(LSTM(32, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))(h_q)
h_q=tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(h_q)
h_q= Bidirectional(LSTM(64, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))(h_q)
h_q=tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(h_q)
h_q = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, activation='tanh'))(h_q)
h_q=tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(h_q)

mu = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_z, activation='linear')(h_q)
log_sigma = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_z, activation='linear')(h_q)
#z_layer
z = keras.layers.Lambda(sample_z, output_shape = (n_z, ))([mu, log_sigma])
z=tf.keras.layers.Reshape((n_z,1))(z)
z_reshaped_one=tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(z)
z_cond = concat([z_reshaped_one, cond],axis=-1) # <--- NEW!
z_reshaped=tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(z_cond)

# Reconstruction decoder
h_p= RepeatVector(22)(z_reshaped)
h_p=tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(h_p)
h_p = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))(h_p)
h_p=tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(h_p)
h_p = Bidirectional(LSTM(64, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))(h_p)
h_p=tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(h_p)
h_p= Bidirectional(LSTM(32, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))(h_p)
h_p=tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(h_p)
h_p = Bidirectional(LSTM(16, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))(h_p)
h_p=tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(h_p)
h_p = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(TimeDistributed(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))(h_p))

X_n = Input(shape=(n_x,1,))
label_n = Input(shape=(n_y,1,))
model_inputs = concat([X_n, label_n],axis=-2)

Model([X_n, label_n], outputs=h_p)#this is where I am getting error








#ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor #KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(1016, 20), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), #name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'") at layer "concatenate_7". The following #previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

Comment: Of course they are disconnected, you defined X_n and label_n later than producing h_p so they are not connected at all. You need to define and use your inputs at the beginning of the code.

Comment: No. Thats not the problem. Even if I define early then also I am getting the error

Comment: I said to define and use, not only define, you are initially using other inputs that are not related at all to the input layers you defined later.